# How to check a value matches with another correpsonding value in a json response

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

What is the most dynamic way of checking each instance of a json response value matches another json response value within a script assertion?

What I mean is lets say I have the following response below:

```
   {
    "xxx": [{
            "roomInformation": [{

                "xxx": xxx

            }],

            "totalPrice": xxx
        },

        {
            "roomInformation": [{
                xxx: xxx
            }],
            "totalPrice": xxx
        }
    ]

}
```

I want to check that the first room price to match with the first `totalPrice` and the second `roomPrice` to match with the second `totalPrice`. It has to be dynamic as I may get many different instances of this so I can't simply just look through the json with [0] and [1]. Virtually check each `roomPrice` matches with its corresponding `totalPrice`.

Thanks

Comment: Have you got some valid JSON?  The JSON in your question is invalid...

Comment: I'll get you some valid json

Comment: Are you using a master / gold copy of already verified copy and current response is going to be compared against it?

Comment: Here you go, valid json included

Comment: Or is it just `roomPrice` is to be matched with `totalPrice` from the same response?

Comment: just roomPrice is to be matched with totalPrice from the same response

Comment: Do you have multiple roomPrices?  Or will there only ever be one?

Comment: There will be only one roomPrice per roomInfomration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `script assertion` to check each `roomPrice` is matching or not with `totalPrice`.

EDIT: based on OP's full response provided [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/vBD42kss)

**Script Assertion**:

```
//Check if the response is not empty
assert context.response, "Response is empty or null"

def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response)
def sb = new StringBuffer()
json.regions.each { region ->
    region.hotels.each { hotel ->
        (hotel?.totalPrice == hotel?.roomInformation[0]?.roomPrice) ?: sb.append("Room price ${hotel?.roomInformation[0]?.roomPrice} is not matching with total price ${hotel.totalPrice}")    
    }
}
if (sb.toString()) {
    throw new Error(sb.toString())
} else { log.info 'Prices match' }
```

Comment: I'm giving this a try Rao along with Tim's answer

Comment: Based on your other response, it may require change in the script.

Answer (score 2):

So given the Json as a variable:

```
def jsonTxt = '''{
    "hotels": [{
            "roomInformation": [{

                "roomPrice": 618.4

            }],

            "totalPrice": 618.4
        },

        {
            "roomInformation": [{
                "roomPrice": 679.79
            }],
            "totalPrice": 679.79
        }
    ]

}'''
```

We can then use the following script:

```
import groovy.json.*

new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonTxt).hotels.each { hotel ->
   assert hotel.roomInformation.roomPrice.sum() == hotel.totalPrice
}
```

As you can see, I'm using `sum` to add all the roomInformation.roomPrice values together.  In  your example, you only have one price, so this will be fine.. And it will also cover the case where you have multiple rooms adding up to make the total

Comment: is 'hotel' like a variable name for each 'hotels'?

Comment: Also if I want to test to see the values with a log.info, what would be the correct way to write the log.info just to ensure it's correct?

Comment: @BruceyBandit Yeah, `hotel` is the name of the variable for `each` element in `hotels`. And if you wanted to log it out, just do `log.info "individual: ${hotel.roomInformation.roomPrice} == total:${hotel.totalPrice}"` or similar