# SoapUI's Script Assertion is failing for the json response

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

I want to check if every instance of `occupanysequenceorder` matches the request inputted for this field. When I do a `log.error` it outputs this:

```
ERROR:[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
ERROR:1
```

So as the request inputted 1, it means in the list all instances needs to equal 1, which it does above. However when I perform an assert:

```
assert roominfo.occupancySequenceOrder.flatten() == occupancysequenceorder_request
```

It throws a false assertion and I am not sure why? How can I get the script assertion to pass with it performing the relevant check. I change assert to 
    `assert roominfo.occupancySequenceOrder.flatten().contains(occupancysequenceorder_request)` and it passes but I am not sure if that is actually does the correct check to ensure every instance of `occupanysequenceorder` is matching the request inputted.

Below is the code:

```
json.testregions.each { roominfo ->
   log.error roominfo.occupancySequenceOrder.flatten()
   log.error occupancysequenceorder_request
   assert roominfo.occupancySequenceOrder.flatten() == occupancysequenceorder_request
}
```

Comment: Have you finally worked out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at OP's other question and its data from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470806/how-to-check-a-value-matches-with-another-correpsonding-value-in-a-json-response)

You can try below `Script Assertion` :

```
//Check if the response is not empty
assert context.response, "Response is empty or null"
//Modify the value of the quest or read it thru properties if you want
def requestValue = 1

def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response)

json.regions.each { region ->
    region.hotels.each { hotel ->
        hotel.roomInformation. each { room ->
            assert room.occupancySequenceOrder == requestValue, "Value did not match for room ${room.hotelRoomId}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @BruceyBandit, have you got chance to try the above?

Answer (score 0):

Rather try:

```
roominfo.occupancySequenceOrder.every { it == 1 }
```

`flatten()` will have no effect on flat `List`.

You may also try:

```
roominfo.occupancySequenceOrder.unique() == [1]
```

if you'd like to compare lists.

Comment: Both methods didn't work opal, it still brings out a false

Comment: The answers are directly related to data that is provided in the question. Better provide right data, so that answers would be accordingly.

Comment: @BruceyBandit please check the data types. There's a chance you're comparing `Integer` with `String`.